# how to solve verilog module instantiation error

Tags: verilog, quartus, intel-fpga

I am trying to connect ports of two modules by instantiating one in the other, but I am encountering this error:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at mlt.v(25) near text: "["; 
>   expecting ")". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear
>   immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA
>   Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how
>   to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at
>   https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html
>   and search for this specific error message number.

I am trying to connect the `[3:0]d` with `in1` and `in2` (for two separate instances).

Here is the code:

```
module mlt(in1,in2,out,clk,en);
input clk;
input en;
input  wire [3:0] in1,in2;
output reg [7:0] out;
reg [7:0]temp_o;
reg t1;
reg [3:0]temp_1;
reg [3:0]temp_2;
wire w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8;


d_latch u1 (.d[0](in1[0]),.d[1](in1[1]),.d[2](in1[2]),.d[3](in1[3]),

.clk(clk),

.q[0](w1),.q[1](w2),.q[2](w3),.q[3](w4));

d_latch u2 (.d[0](in2[0]),.d[1](in2[1]),.d[2](in2[2]),.d[3](in2[3]),

.clk(clk),

.q[0](w5),.q[1](w6),.q[2](w7),.q[3](w8));

//…………
//………

module d_latch (d,clk,q);
    input [3:0]d;
    input clk;
    output reg [3:0]q;

    always @ (posedge clk)
        q<=d;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot break up a port. Use a concatenation, and pay attention to the order the signals appear in that.

```
d_latch u1 (.d(in1),

.clk(clk),

.q({w4,w3,w2,w1}));
```